# Is there is a Facebook real-time streaming API available like the Twitter Stream API?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

Is there is any Facebook stream API available, like the Twitter Stream API? I just want publicly streamed data (Facebook post/comment).

Is there a way to get such a stream via API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no public stream API, but the Realtime API offers subscriptions to Pages and User Profiles:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.1

The Public Post Search is deprecated, so you can´t even use a cron job to get new public posts with specific keywords anymore.

Example Usage: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-facebooks-realtime-updates-and-subscription-api/

Comment: Is there is any example program for the same ??

Comment: i´ve added an article to the answer

Comment: please add a reason for downvotes, so i can improve my answer if neccessary